# Swapping the batch axis has effect on the performance in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, stride

I know that usually the batch dimension is axis zero, and I imagine this has a reason: The underlying memory for each item in the batch is contiguous.

My model calls a function that becomes simpler if I have another dimension in the first axis, so that I can use `x[k]` instead of `x[:, k]`.

Results from arithmetic operations seems to keep the same memory layout

```py
x = torch.ones(2,3,4).transpose(0,1)
y = torch.ones_like(x)
u = (x + 1)
v = (x + y)
print(x.stride(), u.stride(), v.stride())
```

When I create additional variables I am creating them with `torch.zeros` and then transposing, so that the largest stride goes to the axis 1, as well.

e.g.

```py
a,b,c = torch.zeros(
         (3, x.shape[1], ADDITIONAL_DIM, x.shape[0]) + x.shape[2:]
).transpose(1,2)
```

Will create three tensors with the same batch size `x.shape[1]`.
In terms of memory locality it would make any difference to have

```py
a,b,c = torch.zeros(
  (x.shape[1], 3, ADDITIONAL_DIM, x.shape[0]) + x.shape[2:]
).permute(1,2,0, ...)
```

instead.

Should I care about this at all?

Comment: So your question is whether there is any difference between doing a permutation then working with `x[k]`; and working with `x[:, k]` without needing a permutation right?

Comment: Exactly, and also for the internally constructed arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; Slices seemingly contain less information... but in fact share the identical storage buffer with the original tensor. Since permute doesn't affect the underlying memory layout, both operations are essentially equivalent.**

---

Those two are essentially the same, the underlying data storage buffer is kept the same, only the *metadata* *i.e.* how you interact with that buffer (strides and shape) changes.

Let us look at a simple example:

```
>>> x = torch.ones(2,3,4).transpose(0,1)
>>> x_ptr = x.data_ptr()

>>> x.shape, x.stride(), x_ptr
(3, 2, 4), (4, 12, 1), 94674451667072
```

We have kept the data pointer for our 'base' tensor in `x_ptr`:

1. Slicing on the second axis:

   ```
   >>> y = x[:, 0]

   >>> y.shape, y.stride(), x_ptr == y.data_ptr()
   (3, 4), (4, 1), True
   ```

   As you can see, `x` and `x[:, k]` shared the same storage.
2. Permuting the first two axes then slicing on the first one:

   ```
   >>> z = x.permute(1, 0, 2)[0]

   >>> z.shape, z.stride(), x_ptr == z.data_ptr()
   (3, 4), (4, 1), True
   ```

   Here again, you notice that `x.data_ptr` is the same as `z.data_ptr`.

---

In fact, you can even go from `y` to `x`'s representation using [`torch.as_strided`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_strided.html):

```
>>> torch.as_strided(y, size=x.shape, stride=x.stride())
tensor([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Same with `z`:

```
>>> torch.as_strided(z, size=x.shape, stride=x.stride())
```

Both will return a *copy* of `x` because `torch.as_strided` is allocating memory for the newly created tensor. These two lines were just to illustrate how we can still 'get back' to `x` from a slice of `x`, we can recover the apparent content by changing the tensor's metadata.

Comment: Yes, I know all of that, my question is about performance. I am specially interested on how pytorch will parallelize the operations and the performance of the memory transfer using different memory layouts.

Comment: Well, I know this at the surface, I want to know about performance in distributed computing, e.g. in a GPU, without having to write the two implementations and bencmarking

Comment: On either two method, the operations performed will use the same memory storage layout, so yes the performance is the same.

Comment: And what is better is to allocate and assign using slices `a[:] = x + y`  or to to use `a = (x + y).type(a.dtype)`?

Comment: Why not just `a = x + y`? Anyhow both are identical.

Comment: They are not identical. This does not answer my questions, I will accept this answer as is for lack of better answer and for consideration to your effort. When I have time I run some tests on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you saying that? `x[:] = a` will make a copy of `a` yes. However `x[:] = x + y` won't because `x + y` is a temporary variable.

Comment: Because `a[:] = x + y` does not create a new variable, don't discard the reference to an existing tensor. If you have some high level material about how the temporary variables can be represented I would like to see more about it as well. Sometimes I don't know exactly if an operation will produce a physical tensor or some sort of view that can exist without being stored, also if the computation is deferred it must keep a reference to the objects to which it depends, hindering the gc work.

Comment: I don't quite understand your first point: *does not create a new variable* which variable do you refer to here?